# Function Help for Json object

Tags: python, json, function

I am new to python and programing.  I wrote this original script to handle some Facebook data from the open graph.

It works and does produce the .csv I want.

```
def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_time'], msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8'),  msg['from']['id']] for msg in js.get('data', []))

    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)
```

Problems with the above code:

1.) it is long and horrible looking
2.) I want to shorten the total size of 'message' to 900 varchar

In order to accomplish the above I broke messages into a function of its' own:

```
def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance')
    js = json.loads(data)

def extract_info(msg):
    created_time = msg['created_time']
    message = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8')
    user_id = msg['from']['id']
    return (created_time, message, user_id)

    messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('data', []))


    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)
```

I don't get an error when I run this new code but I doesn't print anything either.

Any thoughts into what I did wrong for it not to print.  Since I don't have an error I am little stuck and havent gotten to my 2nd task of shortening the 'message' string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an indentation problem. The last two lines of your second example are inside `extract_info`, not `main`. Try:

```
def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance')
    js = json.loads(data)

    def extract_info(msg):
        created_time = msg['created_time']
        message = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8')
        user_id = msg['from']['id']
        return (created_time, message, user_id)

    messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('data', []))


    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)
```

Or, to prevent the confusion of nested functions:

```
def extract_info(msg):
    created_time = msg['created_time']
    message = msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', '').replace(',', '').encode('utf8')
    user_id = msg['from']['id']
    return (created_time, message, user_id)

def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance')
    js = json.loads(data)
    messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('data', []))
    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed the indents.  Also I really appreciate the advice about nested functions.  Thanks Kevin!